# Google Charts fontsize does not work

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

is it possible to create a Chart with google charts like this in the picture?
My biggest Problem is to get the fontsize on the left smaller.
The second problem is to get the time like 12:00PM 13:00PM 14:00PM
and is it possible to select a timeframe like in the footer on the picture?

[image: Google Chart]

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j29Pt/5/

```js
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'dummy', 'Sales'],
        [12, 0, 440],
        [13, null, 450],
        [14, null, 412],
        [15, null, 434]
    ]);

    var options = {
        series: {
            0: {
                targetAxisIndex: 0,
                visibleInLegend: false,
                pointSize: 0,
                lineWidth: 0
            },
            1: {
                targetAxisIndex: 1,
                visibleInLegend: false,
            }
        },
        colors: ['red'],
        backgroundColor: '#324149',
        chartArea: {
            backgroundColor: {
                stroke: '#fff',
                strokeWidth: 0
            }
        },
        hAxis: {
            gridlines: {
                color: '#37454c',
                count: 7
            },
            textStyle: {
                color: '#fff'
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            gridlines: {
                color: '#37454c',
                count: 7
            },
            textStyle: {
                color: '#525b60',
                fontSize: '3'
            },
            minValue: 390
        },
        vAxes: {
            0: {
                textPosition: 'none'
            },
            1: {
                textPosition: 'in'
            }
        }
    }
    var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your fontSize problem is not due to your code, you have the "Normalized CSS" option checked in the "Fiddle Options" panel, which is messing with the font sizes in the chart.  Uncheck that and your fonts will be the specified size.  Incidentally, the `fontSize` suboption takes a number, not a string, so it should be `fontSize: 3`.

You can add buttons to your HTML that replicate the functionality of the time frame, but the [ChartRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) control performs a similar function without the need for any custom coding.

If you want your axis values formatted as time, you need to use either a "date", "datetime", or "timeofday" type domain (x) axis.  You can then specify the formatting in the chart's `hAxis.format` option.